# Clear default HTML table td values without losing CSS

Tags: javascript, php, forms, html-table

I have multiple HTML tables in a submit form with default values.
These values in the table td are demo values and therefore I want a button to clear all values in 1 table, but keeping the CSS of that table.
This is my table:

HTML table:
[image: HTML table]

I use this code for empty the table:

**updated code**

```
<button>Empty</button>
  <script>
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        $("#table1").find("td").empty();
    });
</script>
```

But when I use this code, my table looks like this:

HTML empty table:

[empty HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmuGn.jpg)

I also tried this:

```
document.getElementById("flagTotal").innerHTML = "";
```

But then the "empty" button wants to submit the form instead of the submit button....?

Can someone provide me with a solution/ tip?

**Update**

Minimal code:

```
div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="table1" class="table table-sw table-bordered">
                <tbody id="tablekrw">
                <tr id="tablehead"><th>Sw</th><th>Krw</th></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="text" class="td-sw" name="sw1[]" value="0.15" id="default-td"></td>
                    <td><input class="td-sw" type="text" name="krw[]" value="0.0"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="text" class="td-sw" name="sw1[]" value="0.18" id="default-td"></td>
                    <td><input class="td-sw" type="text" name="krw[]" value="3.00E-05"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label><button>Empty</button></label></td></tr>
</table>

  <table id="table-right" class="table table-bordered">
                <tr><td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" class="td"><label for="reset" class="label">Reset this form to original
                            values:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset"</tr>
            </table>
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41kXb.jpg)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] (`<>` button in the question editor).

Comment: Keep the CSS? Normally, it doesn't change unless you make it. If it's dynamic, store the values in JavaScript.

Comment: You need to post your HTML for the form. You should make sure your table headings are actually wrapped in `<th></th>` tags and then use something like `$("#table1 td").remove();` to remove the data and keep the headings.

Comment: I've edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the table using the querySelectorAll() method from javascript by just using a foreach loop as the following:

```
function cleanTable() {
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll("#table td");

    fields.forEach(cell => {
      cell.innerHTML = "";
    });
  }
```

If you're not familiar with the querySelector or querySelectorAll here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll. But I tested the code above and it worked.

Call this function when clicking in the empty button, and just make sure your title cells are using the ***th*** tag and not the ***td***.

And also, I believe that if you do not set any width or height for your cells the table will just collapse (but I am not a hundred percent sure, it depends on your css and the frameworks you're using).

Hope it can help!

Comment: Thank you for your input. The problem is when I use "document" or something else than empty() in my script and I click the empty button, I get an error to fill a required empty input field somewhere on my form... I have no idea why.. I've edit my question and the last picture shows the message in my form.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. JavaScript:

```
function emptyTable() {
$('#empty1').click( function() {
    $(this).closest('table').find('input').val('');
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr><td><button type="button" id="empty1">empty Sw, Krw table</button></td></tr>

<script>emptyTable();</script>
```

Now the table td values dissapear without the table collapsing.